# Extend image field in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x, typo3-12.x

I would like to extend image field of tt_content table in TYPO3 backend and add extra button that will load potential image from external source. How can I actually edit such a view in TYPO3 11 and/or 12?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not necessary to extend the image field. What would you achieve? What is with an additional file storage for external resources? What exactly means: "external source"?